# pythonic way of reading a flattened dict in an input file

Tags: python, parsing, input

I am reading an input file that essentially contains a nested flattened dictionary, like this:

```
&HEADER
header line 0
header line 1
&End_HEADER
some other line 1
some other line 2
#XXX0
line 0
line 1
line 2
#AAA0
line 0
line 1
line 2
...
#AAA1
line 0
line 1
...
#BBB0
line 0
line 1
...
#BBB1
line 0
...
#XXX1
line 0
...
#AAA0
line 0
...
#AAA1
...
#BBB0
...
```

You can notice there are three parts, each formed by several lines: the header, some individual lines, and a flattened nested dictionary. I am most interested in the latter, but Ideally I would like to parse it so that I get the following:

```
{
    'HEADER': ['header line 0', 'header line 1'],
    'other lines': ['some other line 1', 'some other line 2'],
    'XXX0': {
        'HEADER': ['line 0', 'line 1', 'line 2'],
        'AAA0': ['line 0', 'line 1', 'line 2', '...'],
        'AAA1': ['line 0', 'line 1', '...'],
        'BBB0': ['line 0', 'line 1', '...'],
        'BBB1': ['line 0', '...']
    },
    'XXX1': {
        'HEADER': ['line 0', '...'],
        'AAA0': ['line 0', '...'],
        'AAA1': ['...'],
        'BBB0': ['...']
    }
}
```

I am currently iterating through each line and using if statements to append each line to a nested dictionary. It works, but it is ugly and I suspect this could be done more elegantly, perhaps using recursion, defaultdict or regular expressions. I cannot get my head around it. Can you please help me find a better way find out a better way? Many thanks.

Comment: If it's possible to create a small function to work on each block, you could do that. Then do some sort of string.split to get the blocks separate and then just do a dict comprehension to pull it all together.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I had in mind. `Pythonic` is fairly subjective but this approach could make it easy to follow? This does not cover the top header part but that can be parsed easily too. Once you parse that you can just merge the dictionaries together.

```py
import re
import json
import itertools

a = """
&HEADER
header line 0
header line 1
&End_HEADER
some other line 1
some other line 2
#XXX0
line 0
line 1
line 2
#AAA0
line 0
line 1
line 2
...
#AAA1
line 0
line 1
...
#BBB0
line 0
line 1
...
#BBB1
line 0
...
#XXX1
line 0
...
#AAA0
line 0
...
#AAA1
...
#BBB0
...
"""

# split the text into chunks that should be a key to the dictionary
splits = re.finditer(r"(#XXX[0-9])", a)
# this is a list of tuples. each tuple tells you where in a '#XXX0', '#XXX1' etc
# occur. These will be the keys in the dictionary.
spans = [group.span() for group in splits]

# we need to get text from were a group begins and where the other begins etc
blocks = list(itertools.chain(*spans)) + [len(a)]

# we just want to take 2 indices at a time i.e. where the text for
# '#XXX0' begins and where '#XXX1' starts.
blocks_gen = iter(blocks[1:])
blocks = [tuple(next(blocks_gen) for _ in range(2)) for __ in range(len(blocks[1:]) // 2)]

def block_parse(block: tuple):
    """
    A block is just a tuple. say (0, 10) for example. This should indicate that
    the substring of the flatten text from 0 to 10 is a block of text that needs
    to be processed and assigned to a dictionary.
    """
    block_string = a[block[0]: block[1]]
    header, body = block_string.split("#", 1)

    header = {'HEADER': header.strip().split('\n')}

    body = body.split('#')
    body = [body_.strip().split('\n') for body_ in body]
    body = dict((body_[0], body_[1:]) for body_ in body)

    return {**header, **body}

assert len(spans) == len(blocks)

my_dict = {a[spans[i][0]:spans[i][1]]: block_parse(blocks[i]) for i in range(len(blocks))}

print(json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4))
```

Output:

```py
{
    "#XXX0": {
        "HEADER": [
            "line 0",
            "line 1",
            "line 2"
        ],
        "AAA0": [
            "line 0",
            "line 1",
            "line 2",
            "..."
        ],
        "AAA1": [
            "line 0",
            "line 1",
            "..."
        ],
        "BBB0": [
            "line 0",
            "line 1",
            "..."
        ],
        "BBB1": [
            "line 0",
            "..."
        ]
    },
    "#XXX1": {
        "HEADER": [
            "line 0",
            "..."
        ],
        "AAA0": [
            "line 0",
            "..."
        ],
        "AAA1": [
            "..."
        ],
        "BBB0": [
            "..."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I could hardly call this pythonic. I am having trouble understanding what is going on.

Comment: Np. If you run it line by line it will certainly make sense. The goal is simple. Identify where each "#XXX0' etc. occur. The text between '#XXX0' and '#XXX1' should go with 'XXX0' and so on. So a small function that can be used to process each of these text blocks between each '#XXX0' and '#XXX1' is what I created. But then again what I call pythonic is not what someone else would call pythonic

Comment: Thanks for the added comments, I can follow better now.